# Inequality form olympiad

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let a , b , c be real numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=2$

> Show that $a+b+c \leq abc+2$

Please help. I'm stuck on this one. I tried a lot of things. The problem is I can't use standard inequalities because they're not necessarily positive.

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h54136p338233, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h32399, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h478215.

Comment: Can you solve it when $a,b,c$ are positive?

Answer (score 1):

**Proof 1.** Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$[a(1-bc) +(b+c)]^2 \leqslant [a^2+(b+c)^2][(1-bc)^2+1] = 2(1+bc)[(1-bc)^2+1].$$
Thefore, we need to prove
$$(1+bc)[(1-bc)^2+1] \leqslant 2,$$
or
$$b^2c^2(bc-1) \leqslant 0.$$
Which is true because
$$bc \leqslant \frac{b^2+c^2}{2} \leqslant \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}=1.$$
Done.

**Proof 2.** We need to prove
$$4-(a+b+c-abc)^2 \geqslant 0.$$
equivalent to
$$4-(a+b+c)^2+2abc(a+b+c)-4a^2b^2c^2 \geqslant 0.$$
Setting $A=a^2+b^2+c^2=2,$ the inequality equivalent to
$$4[4-(a+b+c)^2+2abc(a+b+c)-a^2b^2c^2] \ge 0$$
or
$$2^3-2^2 \cdot [(a+b+c)^2-2]+2 \cdot 4abc \cdot (a+b+c)-4a^2b^2c^2\geqslant 0,$$
$$A^3-A^2\cdot\left[(a+b+c)^2-A\right]+4 \cdot A \cdot abc \cdot (a+b+c)-4a^2b^2c^2 \geqslant  0,$$
or
$$(2-2ab)(2-2bc)(2-2ca)+4a^2b^2c^2 \geqslant 0.$$
Which is true because
$$2-2ab=(a^2-2ab+b^2)+c^2=(a-b)^2+c^2 \geqslant 0.$$
The proof is completed.